# What is the difference between raw and keyword fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 7, consider these three mappings:

```
        "properties" : {
             "actors" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "fields" : {"keyword" : {"type" : "keyword","ignore_above" : 25}}
             },
```

and

```
  "properties" : {
             "actors" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "fields" : {"raw" : {"type" : "keyword","ignore_above" : 25}}
             },
```

and

```
  "properties" : {
             "actors" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "fields" : {"custom_field" : {"type" : "keyword","ignore_above" : 25}}
             },
```

What is the difference between

- actors.keyword
- actors.raw
- actors.custom_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are same. They are just three fields with type as keyword, having different names

Answer (score 0):

They are just preference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/multi-fields.html

FYI, ElasticSearch version >= 5 have two string types:

- text
- keyword

From your example: actors is text type.
Then by default it will perform full-text-search.
If you want to do exact-match search on this field, you will need to custom your parameters by adding either keyword, raw, custom_field at the end.

Example:

```
 # There are records
   {
     actors: "hello world"
   },
   {
     actors: "hello mom"
   }
```

**Default search will perform full-text search:**

```
GET products/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "actors": "hello"
   }
 }
}
actors: "hello" => will return 2 above records.
```

**If you want to perform keyword search (exact match) then we need to custom your parameter as the following:**

```
#1 
GET products/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "actors.keyword": "hello"
   }
 }
}
#2  
GET products/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "actors.raw": "hello"
   }
 }
}
#3
GET products/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "actors.custom_field": "hello"
   }
 }
}
```